# Adding user elements multidimensional array using methods Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

The following is my problem: 
"Create a program that keeps track of the following information input by the user:
First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, Age
Now - let's store this in a multidimensional array that will hold 10 of these contacts. So our multidimensional array will need to be 10 rows and 4 columns.
You should be able to add, display and remove contacts in the array.
"
**FixedThis(I'm stuck at the point of creating a method to call back and enter the users input into my 2 dimensional array.)

**New problem, I get an error for case 3, I cant seem to return the method to print the display, any suggestions to fix this?

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2
{
    String[][] myArray = new String[10][4];

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Lab2();
    }

    public Lab2()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Contact Directory, please select from following: ");
            System.out.println("Type 1 to add contact, 2 to remove contact, 3 to display contacts and 0 to exit.");
            int intChoice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();

            String strFirstName; 
            String strLastName;
            switch(intChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter First Name");
                strFirstName = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
                strLastName = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Phone Number");
                String strPhoneNumber = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Age");
                String strAge = input.nextLine();

                addItem(strFirstName, strLastName, strPhoneNumber, strAge);
                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter First Name to Remove");
                strFirstName = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Last Name to Remove");
                strLastName = input.nextLine();

                removeItem(strFirstName, strLastName);
                break;
                case3:// GETTING AN ERROR UNREACHABLE STATEMENT
                displayItems();
                break;
                case 0:
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addItem(String strFirstName, String strLastName,
    String strPhoneNumber, String strAge)
    {

       for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
        {
           if (myArray[i][0] == null)
           {
               myArray[i][0] = strFirstName;
               myArray[i][1] = strLastName;
               myArray[i][2] = strPhoneNumber;
               myArray[i][3] = strAge;
               ; break;
            }
       }
    }
}

    public void removeItem(String strFirstName, String strLastName)
    {
         int i, j;

         for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
         {
             for(j = 0; j < myArray.length - 1; j++){
                     myArray[i][j] = myArray[i + 1][j];
                     break;
                }
            }
        }

    public void displayItems()
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Note that the runnable code blocks are for js (JavaScript). You won't be able to run Java code blocks in the browser.

Comment: I would suggest adding a new question if you're having a new different problem. It will probably go unnoticed since the original is already marked as resolved. Plus, ideally, one question deals with one problem.

Comment: ...but, since it will probably get closed as a typographical error, add a space between `case` and `3`. `case3:` should be `case 3:`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint you have should be the code used to fix your problem. Find the next available and add it.

```
    if (myArray[i][0] == null)
    {
        myArray[i][0] = strFirstName;
        myArray[i][1] = strLastName;
        myArray[i][2] = strPhoneNumber;
        myArray[i][3] = strAge;
        blnInserted = true; 
        break;
    }
```

You don't need the second loop because you're just checking if the entire entry is `null` based on the first name. The code should be added in the section where you're confused after removing the enclosing second loop.

Also, the `null` check after the `||` is not needed. If it's `null` you won't be able to check equality since doing so would require an instance which can't be `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ChiefTwoPencils... I fixed my code (btw should I just put my Java code in the comments section then?)

Comment: @user3117238, no problem; always glad to help. If you're referring to my edit and comment on your post, no. Just put your code in the post area, select it, and click the `{}` button in the editor. That way it will highlighted as code but not as runnable code. You can also choose to click the button first which will inject a code block for you before hand.